# Urban or Epic Fantasy?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, fantasy

I can't decide what I want to write about: Should I go with urban or epic fantasy? And what are the pros and cons of them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is just way to broad and at its heart is a matter of personal interest and opinion. What should I write questions don’t help other writers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the story you want to write.  Remember you will spend months and months writing and revising it.  That's a long time to spend with it.  You want the one you can stand for that long.

Besides, chasing trends is a good way to enter an oversaturated market with all the other works that were chasing it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to decide what to write:

1. What interests you (more, now)?

   It is easier to work hard on something that is close to your heart and to write a story that you *want* to tell. Writing stories that you don't care about can be done, if you approach writing like any other job, but, like any other job, you won't feel as passionate about it and because of that there is a higher likelihood of eventual boredom or burnout.
2. What does the market currently want?

   Many good books aren't published because there is (currently) no market for them (or agents and publishers believe that there isn't). Books, like any other market, follow trends, and certain genres or themes sell better than others at times. People working in the book publishing industry (agents, editors, book sellers) report on the current or upcoming trends in industry publications, and writing what agents and publishers want to buy might better guarantee success than writing against the trends.

So:

- Does urban fantasy sell better or worse than epic fantasy at the moment?
- Does urban fantasy interest you less or more than epic fantasy at the moment?

You should also consider that quite probably the first novel you are going to write (if this is your first) is going to be a failure. If you are a beginning writer, you will have a lot to learn yet, and it will likely take you a few books to learn it. [On average, writers write about three books before their debut novel.](https://medium.com/@Ava_Jae/how-many-books-did-you-write-before-you-published-your-debut-6711d7e73c92) So don't agonize too much over the genre of the first one. Just write *something*.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with having a story that needs to be told. If you can't think of a story you want to tell, why bother trying to write at all?

If you have two stories and can't decide which one to tell first, go with the one that's itching you more, or with the one you feel like working on right now, or with the one that's simpler and will be done sooner, or the one you've got better thought through. Put the other one on the back burner and return to it later.